# Can we say something like "promoting bad ethics"?

Tags: word-choice

I am a non-native researcher and I am currently working on an academic report about education. In one of my sentences, I want to introduce the consequences of a particular misusing behavior. However, I am not sure how to describe the damage to ethics.

My text:

> The consequences of this misusing behavior include diminished learning, imposing poor well-being to students, and ... ethics.

I want to say "promoting bad ethics." Does this make sense? Do you kindly have any suggestions for me to improve my sentence? Thank you so much for your time and help in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "this misusing behavior"?  That phrasing is strange, and understanding what you mean might help us give you a better answer.

Comment: You already used "impose" which could be a good alternative, another one - "enforce"

Comment: You impose _on_ not _to_

Comment: The consequences of this **negative** behavior include....and **damage to ethics**. If you don't have a specific impairment in mind, keep it general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The consequences of this **misuse** include diminished learning, **the
> imposition of** poor well-being **unto/on** (unto is a little fancy
> and kind of obsolete... but you can't use to) students, and **the
> promotion of** bad ethics.

This isn't a formal rule but, when you write an enumeration, it's always cleaner to list either verbs or nouns, when possible. As long as you know what promotion means, this is absolutely fine. "Misusing behaviour" is redundant, in a sense where you can be just as specific and less "abstract" in using fewer words.

Next time, if you're comfortable with it, specify your native language so someone can give you examples in that language. Good luck with your report.